# Слово "семья"

Tags: этимология

Часто в ребусах слово "семья" загадывают как "7-я". Действительно это слово состоит из "семь-я" или это совпадение?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Слова "семья" и "7-я" омонимы. На самом деле слово **СЕМЬЯ** по происхождению представляет собой форму собир. сущ. с суф. -uj-а > ьj-а (ср. ст.-сл. **сЪмий** «челядь, рабы», устар. братиΙΑ «братья»). Сущ. СѢМИΙΑ образовано от сущ. сѢмь «работник, слуга», «домочадец», которое происходит от праслав. *semьj* sěimь «слуга». В слове *sémь корень* sě- /*si-n суф. -m-ь. Этот же корень с суф. -v. отмечается в и.-е.* seva/*siva «милый, приятный»; др.- инд. cevas «искренний, милый»; лат. civic «гражданин», civilis «гражданский», из первонач. «учтивый, вежливый». От лат. civilis в рус. яз. сущ.* цивилизация* «уровень общественного развития». Это слово появилось во франц. яз., откуда в XIX в. проникло во многие другие яз.

Числительное СЕМЬ имеет несколько иное происхождение. Соврем. его форма возникла в результате преобразования др.-рус. **седмь** «семь», в котором на почве диалектов, легших в основу вост.-слав. языков, упростилось сочетание дм > м (Сравните: се**дьм**ой, се**дм**ица). Др-рус. *седмь* «семь» восходит к праслав. *sedmъ, которое первонач. 
было порядковым числительным «седьмой», а затем стало восприниматься как 
количественное.

Comment: А слово "семя" какое-нибудь отношение к упомянутым имеет?

Answer (score 0):

В первом посте предполагается родственность *сем - сев*, что довольно сомнительно. Следующие посты о семёрке - вообще блажь. Слово семь имеет сакральное значение не только для человека, но и для всего живого на Земле, потому что зависит от лунного календаря, когда во время полнолуний (иногда новолуний) раскачиваются тектонические разломы с выделением энергии и усвоением её по типу первичного питания. Поэтому больные и желающие зачать (родить) всегда стараются попасть во время полнолуния в сильную зону разлома.

Comment: @turgen, здесь занимаются вопросами русского языка, а не исследуем эзотерику. Если у вас есть что сказать, пишите по существу!

Answer (score 0):

Я всегда мала, что "семья" - собирательное от корня "сем+ja" из слова "СЕМЯ", то есть семья- это собирательное название СООБЩЕСТВА, СОЖИТЕЛЬСТВА  людей из одного фактически СЕМЕНИ. Свидетельством тому был и тот факт, что все и даже ЖЕНА(то есть человек из другого СЕМЕНИ), жили под одной и той же фамилией.

Comment: Версия любопытная, но, к сожалению, нет. Слова "семя" писалось через ять:   СѢМЯ и родственно СѢЯТЬ, СѢВ. В "семья" ятя не было. Это полдностью исключает какое-либо родство на славянском уровне. Впрочем, а на более древних этапах они совсем далеки друг от друга (см. ответ olsa).